# Rows per page doesn't locate correctly

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

rows per page is not working correctly, it locates at right side[image: screenshot of the page] how can I fix it? firstly it didn't show then I added  and in console it showed warning, than I added app-data = "true" then it was fixed, but dropdown didn't work correctly.

```
<template>
    <div app-data="true">
        <v-app id="app">
            <v-content>
                <v-card>
                    <v-card-title>
                    Nutrition
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-text-field
                        v-model="search"
                        append-icon="search"
                        label="Search"
                        single-line
                        hide-details
                    ></v-text-field>
                    </v-card-title>
                    <v-data-table
                    :headers="headers"
                    :items="desserts"
                    :search="search"
                    >
                    <template v-slot:items="props">
                        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
                        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
                        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
                        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
                        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
                        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
                    </template>
                    <template v-slot:no-results>
                        <v-alert :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
                        Your search for "{{ search }}" found no results.
                        </v-alert>
                    </template>
                    </v-data-table>
                </v-card>
            </v-content>
        </v-app>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: what is the console warning? what is your css?

Comment: seems to [work](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNyGRV?&editable=true&editors=101)